# cv2 module is not capturing the image while the code is detecting the webcam

Tags: python, python-2.7, opencv, rgb, video-capture

The code I used is:

```
import cv2

camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
im=camera.read()[1]
print im
```

for which I'm getting output as  **None**
 In some cases it is returning the RGB values but not every time i want.
In which cases it will return None??

Answer (score 1):

Your Question is:

> In which cases it will return None??

This can be easily found in the documentation of [VideoCapture](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/videoio/doc/reading_and_writing_video.html).
For the function read it states:

> The methods/functions combine VideoCapture::grab() and
>   VideoCapture::retrieve() in one call. This is the most convenient
>   method for reading video files or capturing data from decode and
>   return the just grabbed frame. I**f no frames has been grabbed** (camera
>   has been disconnected, or there are no more frames in video file), **the
>   methods return false and the functions return NULL pointer.**

So the connection to your camera seems to be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
import cv2

cv2.namedWindow('webCam')

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)


if cap.isOpened():
    ret, frame = cap.read()
else:
    ret = False
    print "problem here"


while True:
    #get frames
    ret,frame = cap.read()
    frame = cv2.flip(frame,1)  # flip image 

    cv2.imshow('webCam', frame)  # show cam

    # to exit
    esc = cv2.waitKey(5) & 0xFF == 27
    if esc:
        break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```